# BadRequestError: Nested transactions are not supported

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, google-cloud-datastore, jinja2

I'm currently learning about [transactions](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/transactions) and I'm getting this error message:

> BadRequestError: Nested transactions are not supported

I have no idea how to resolve this. Any assistance will be appreciated.

**main.py**

```
import webapp2
import jinja2
import os
import datetime

from google.appengine.ext import db

jinja_environment = jinja2.Environment(
    loader=jinja2.FileSystemLoader(os.path.dirname(__file__)))

class MainPage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self):          
        transaction_status = create_message_txn("Python_Board", "message name", "Message Title", "Here is the message text")

        message = Message.all()

        template_values = {
            'transaction_status': transaction_status,
            'message': message,
        }       

        template = jinja_environment.get_template('index.html')
        self.response.out.write(template.render(template_values))


class MessageStore(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def post(self):
        message = Message()
        message.message_title = self.request.get('message_title')       
        message.message_text = self.request.get('message_text')     
        photo.put() 
        self.redirect('/')      


class MessageBoard(db.Expando):
    pass


class Message(db.Expando):
    pass

def create_message_txn(board_name, message_name, message_title, message_text):
    board = db.get(db.Key.from_path('MessageBoard', board_name))
    if not board:
        board = MessageBoard(key_name=board_name)
        board.count = 0

    message = Message(key_name=message_name, parent=board)
    message.title = message_title
    message.text = message_text
    message.post_date = datetime.datetime.now()

    board.count += 1

    db.put([board, message])

    try:
        db.run_in_transaction(create_message_txn, board_name=board_name,
        message_name=message_title,
        message_title=message_title,
        message_text=message_text)
    except db.TransactionFailedError, e:
        transaction_status = "Transaction failed: %s " %e 

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                                ('/new_message',MessageStore)], debug=True)
```

**index.html**

```
<html>
    <body>                      
        <form action="/new_photo" method="post">            
            <label for="message_title">Message Title</label>
            <div><textarea name="message_title" rows="1" cols="60" id="message_title"></textarea></div>         
            <label for="message_text">Message Text</label>
            <div><textarea name="message_text" rows="3" cols="60" id="message_text"></textarea></div>                       
            <input type="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>
        <div><hr></hr></div>        
        <div><b>{{ transaction_status }}</b></div>          
        <div><hr></hr></div>            
        {% for m in message(limit=5): %}
        <div><b>{{ m.title }}</b></div>
        <div>{{ m.text }}</div>
        <div>{{ m.date }}</div>
        <div><hr></hr></div>        
        <b>{% endfor %}</b>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

it looks like you are recursivley calling `create_message_txn`

```
def create_message_txn():

    # code happening here
    db.run_in_transaction(create_message_txn, board_name=board_name
```

^ `run_in_transaction` calls `create_message_txn` which calls `run_in_transaction` which calls ect...

You could fix this by breaking up the code you want to run as transaction into a separate function

Comment: +1 Thanks for your reply. I am new to transactions, I just started learning Google App engine. I hacked this code together, trying to understand how transactions work. How am I recursively calling create_message_txn? Can you recommend a simple example that shows transactions in action?

Comment: @Anthony your error isn't related to transactions it is related to your program design, transactions are nice because the whole transaction either fails or succeeds,  the classic example is banking,  for you to make a payment to someone it is 2 part process, withdraw money from your account and credit to someone elses,  This requires 2 queries.  If your account is withdrawn and then there is an error, you are out money and the other person never got credited! `run_in_transaction` allows you to execute multipart queries that either complete all parts or no parts

Comment: Ok, I'm going to try and rewrite this and come back shortly.